# Will i get the rewards of reading Quran in arabic by reading an English Quranic Transliteration?

Tags: quran

Will I get the rewards of reading an arabic Quran by reading an English Transliteration of it  ?

Comment: It is certainly better to learn the Arabic letters and read them. As the hadith about rewards for reading explicitly mentions them. But this doesn't mean that scholars may come to a different conclusion. Note that one can not read the qur'an as the qur'an itself is orally transmitted you read from a Moshaf (a physical copy of the quranic text).